# Why is the print statement in 'else' clause still executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and this is my code. When I input 'banana', the result is 'banana is fruite' but it also prints 'unknown' from the 'else' clause. Why?

```
product = str(input("Chose Product : "))

if product == "banana" or product == "apple" or product == "kiwi" or product == "lemon":
    print(f"{product} is fruite")
if product == "pepper" or product == "tomato" or product == "cucumber" or product == "carrot":
    print(f"{product} is vegetable")

else:
    print("unknown")
```

Comment: Make the second `if` an `elif` so that it's part of the same conditional instead of a whole new one.  Also, you don't need `str` around your `input` call, it already returns a `str`.  :)

Comment: you need to use `elif`, as you are using two `If` block, so after getting resutl from first block, it check for second block, it is not there so `else` part is printed

Comment: also it's a little easier to do `if product in ("banana", "apple", "kiwi", "lemon"):` instead of all the `or`s...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
product = str(input("Chose Product : "))


if product == "banana" or product == "apple" or product == "kiwi" or product == "lemon":
    print(f"{product} is fruite")
elif product == "pepper" or product == "tomato" or product == "cucumber" or product == "carrot":
    print(f"{product} is vegetable")
else:
    print("unknown")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
product = str(input("Chose Product : "))

if product == "banana" or product == "apple" or product == "kiwi" or product == "lemon":
    print(f"{product} is fruite")
elif product == "pepper" or product == "tomato" or product == "cucumber" or product == "carrot":
    print(f"{product} is vegetable")
else:
    print("unknown")
```

`elif` chains the else to the first if.
In your code, else only executes when the second if is not True, but the first if works seperately.

Comment: omg im so dumb thx man <3

Comment: Thanks. Please consider confirming the answer bro

Answer (score 0):

if you will not chain if with elif then the else will work if the if above the else is false.

this code works

```
product = str(input("Chose Product : "))
if product == "banana" or product == "apple" or product == "kiwi" or product == "lemon":

    print(f"{product} is fruite")
elif product == "pepper" or product == "tomato" or product == "cucumber" or product == "carrot":
    print(f"{product} is vegetable")

else:
    print("unknown")
```

just replaced the middle if with elif to maintain the chain

Answer (score -1):

use elif instead of if in second condition.